# Are all hostas edible?

Tags: hosta

My mom loves having hostas around the yard, and garden, so I was wondering if all of them are edible, or just some of them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the edibility of a plant. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: A lot of gardening is growing food. There is nothing wring with converting your garden to a food source.

Comment: @NiallC. Do you want to move this to biology instead?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Or would it be better at Cooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems they are - they belong to the Asparagacaea family, and are apparently eaten frequently in Japan and other countries. As with many food plants, the young leaves are best - older leaves can become tough, stringy and bitter. Some varieties are used more commonly than others as vegetables, H. seiboldii and H.montana, but they can all be eaten. They'll behave like a cut and come again crop, producing more leaves to replace those you've cropped. More info here

http://rawedibleplants.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/hosta-species.html

and here

https://scottishforestgarden.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/hostas/

Comment: So Hosta Kimchi is a possibility. May have to try that.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - yea, let us know how it goes, or more importantly, how it tastes!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosta#Toxicity), all hostas are edible. But do not trust me or Wikipedia blindly.

In any case, I would not eat it too much and too often.